# Are there any good libraries of functions to use with collections in Java, such as

Tags: java, open-source, function, libraries

Are there any good libraries of functions to use with collections in Java.  I'm thinking along the lines of implementations of partition, take, drop, takeWhile, dropWhile, map, filter, reduce...?  I can write them myself, but it feels like re-inventing the wheel.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) is awesome.

Comment: take, drop, takeWhile or dropWhile?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Collections (Guava)](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) is great!  `Collections2` and `Iterables` are utility classes worth looking at.  They both have a filter and transform (like map) method, among many other things.

Comment: Guava looks, ok...  but I see nothing like take, drop, takeWhile or dropWhile

Answer (score 0):

[apache Commons-Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/)